# Building a whole website frontend using Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a whole website which depends only on material UI component, will that affect the performance of thee speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance won't be affected based solely on the library you are using. The data you require and how you are getting it is what matters.